# UIScrollView上でズームした時のUIImageViewをセンタリングorリサイズしたい

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

UIScrollViewの上にUIImageViewを乗せてピンチで縮小/拡大とダブルタップで最大倍率/最小倍率
というズームをしているのですが、画像の高さが小さい画像でズームすると
下の写真のように、何もない領域を表示できてしまいます。
試行錯誤してみましたが解決策がわからず質問させて頂きました。

解決策のご教授お願い致します。

---

### 画像

[自アプリズーム前]......(問題発生)[自アプリズーム後]......(目標)[デフォルト写真アプリズーム後]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力] [image: 画像の説明をここに入力] [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

### 現状

[image: レイヤー]

1. AutoLayout使用なし
2. view contentMode →scaleToFill
   scrollView contentMode→scaleToFill
   ImageView→AspectFit
3. self.view.frame == self.scrollview.frame == self.mainImageView.frame;
   三つとも同じフレームで被せています。

   ※RMP~はナビゲーションバーを使ったカスタム画面移動のOSSです。
   [RMPZoomTransitionAnimator/GitHub](https://github.com/recruit-mp/RMPZoomTransitionAnimator)

---

### 当該コード

< DetailViewController.h>

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RMPZoomTransitionAnimator.h"
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController<RMPZoomTransitionAnimating, RMPZoomTransitionDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *mainImageView;

@end
```

< DetailViewController.m>

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#define DEFAULT_ZOOM_SCALE 1.0
#define SCALE_RATE 3.0

@interface DetailViewController ()<UIScrollViewDelegate>
//zoom when doubleTap.
- (void)onDoubleTapOnPhoto:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = DEFAULT_ZOOM_SCALE;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = SCALE_RATE;
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onDoubleTapOnPhoto:)];
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (void)onDoubleTapOnPhoto:(id)sender
{

    float zoom = self.scrollView.zoomScale;

    CGPoint tapPoint = [sender locationInView:self.scrollView];

    // Zoom=self.scrollView.zoom → Zoom=1.0
    tapPoint.x /= zoom;
    tapPoint.y /= zoom;

    if (zoom >self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale)
    {
        // already max zoom : set zoom to default
        [self.scrollView setZoomScale:DEFAULT_ZOOM_SCALE animated:YES];
    } else
    {
        // zoom up

        float newZoom = zoom * SCALE_RATE;
        if (newZoom >= self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale)
        {
            newZoom = self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale;
        }

        CGRect newRect = [self zoomRectForScrollView:self.scrollView
                                           withScale:newZoom
                                          withCenter:tapPoint];
        [self.scrollView zoomToRect:newRect animated:YES];
    }
}

#pragma - scrollViewZooming
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.mainImageView;
}

- (CGRect)zoomRectForScrollView:(UIView *)scrollView withScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center {

    CGRect zoomRect;

    // The zoom rect is in the content view's coordinates.
    // At a zoom scale of 1.0, it would be the size of the
    // imageScrollView's bounds.
    // As the zoom scale decreases, so more content is visible,
    // the size of the rect grows.
    zoomRect.size.height = scrollView.frame.size.height / scale;
    zoomRect.size.width  = scrollView.frame.size.width  / scale;

    // choose an origin so as to get the right center.
    zoomRect.origin.x = center.x - (zoomRect.size.width  / 2.0);
    zoomRect.origin.y = center.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0);

    return zoomRect;
}

#pragma mark - <RMPZoomTransitionAnimating>

- (UIImageView *)transitionSourceImageView
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.mainImageView.image];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    imageView.frame = self.mainImageView.frame;

    return imageView;
}

- (UIColor *)transitionSourceBackgroundColor
{
    return self.view.backgroundColor;
}

- (CGRect)transitionDestinationImageViewFrame
{
    return self.mainImageView.frame;
}

#pragma mark - <RMPZoomTransitionDelegate>

- (void)zoomTransitionAnimator:(RMPZoomTransitionAnimator *)animator
         didCompleteTransition:(BOOL)didComplete
      animatingSourceImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView
{
    self.mainImageView.image = imageView.image;

}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決する事が出来ました。
この解決法のポイントは以下

> **1. UIImageViewはIBから生成しない(プログラムから生成する)**
>   2. リサイズする
>   3. 初期化後とズーム後にセンタリングする

---

[detailView.h]

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RMPZoomTransitionAnimator.h"
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController<RMPZoomTransitionAnimating, RMPZoomTransitionDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *mainScrollView;
//IBOutlet辞めました
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *mainImageView;

@end
```

[DetailView.m]書き換え分のみ

```
//僕の場合、カスタム画面移動の具合でこのメソッドでimageが受け渡されるのでここでUIImageViewを生成しています
//普通はviewDidLoadでUIImageを作って入れても問題ないと思います。
- (void)zoomTransitionAnimator:(RMPZoomTransitionAnimator *)animator
         didCompleteTransition:(BOOL)didComplete
      animatingSourceImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView
{
    UIImage *resizedImage = [self.class resizeAspectFitWithSize:imageView.image size:CGSizeMake(self.mainScrollView.frame.size.width, self.mainScrollView.frame.size.height)];
    self.mainImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:resizedImage];
    [self.mainScrollView addSubview:self.mainImageView];
    [self centeringContents];
    NSLog(@"imagewidth:%f imageheight:%f",_mainImageView.image.size.width,_mainImageView.image.size.height);
    NSLog(@"viewwidth:%f viewheight:%f",_mainImageView.frame.size.width,_mainImageView.frame.size.height);


}

+ (UIImage*)resizeAspectFitWithSize:(UIImage *)srcImg size:(CGSize)size {

    CGFloat widthRatio  = size.width  / srcImg.size.width;
    CGFloat heightRatio = size.height / srcImg.size.height;
    CGFloat ratio = (widthRatio < heightRatio) ? widthRatio : heightRatio;

    CGSize resizedSize = CGSizeMake(srcImg.size.width*ratio, srcImg.size.height*ratio);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(resizedSize, NO, 0);
    [srcImg drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, resizedSize.width, resizedSize.height)];
    UIImage* resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return resizedImage;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self centeringContents];
}
- (void)centeringContents
{
    CGSize boundsSize = self.mainScrollView.bounds.size;
    CGRect frameToCenter = self.mainImageView.frame;

    // center horizontally
    if (frameToCenter.size.width < boundsSize.width)
    {
        frameToCenter.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - frameToCenter.size.width) / 2;
    } else {
        frameToCenter.origin.x = 0;
    }

    // center vertically
    if (frameToCenter.size.height < boundsSize.height)
    {
        frameToCenter.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - frameToCenter.size.height) / 2;
    } else {
        frameToCenter.origin.y = 0;
    }
    NSLog(@"x:%f y:%f width:%f height:%f",frameToCenter.origin.x,frameToCenter.origin.y,frameToCenter.size.width,frameToCenter.size.height);
    self.mainImageView.frame = frameToCenter;

}
```

---

やけくそになっていじくってたら出来たので成功理由は定かでないです。
ただ、IB利用時にはセンタリングのメソッドを使ってもうまくいかなかった事を考えると

- contentMode(ImageViewの)
- ImageViewのframe
- UIImageViewのinitWithImageの自動リサイズがうまく作用した

のどれかかな。と考えています。

Answer (score -1):

```
// - (void)onDoubleTapOnPhoto:(id)sender
- (void)onDoubleTapOnPhoto:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    float zoom = self.scrollView.zoomScale;

    CGPoint tapPoint = [sender locationInView:self.scrollView];
```

このように、メソッドの引数を変更してみてください。
メソッド`locationInView:`は、`UIGestureRecognizer`のメソッドなので、`sender`の型は`UIGestureRecognizer`かそのサブクラスでなければ、機能しません。